# How can i install tomboy on CentOS 7?

Tags: yum, package-management, rpm, centos-7, tomboy

I downloaded tomboy-1.15.4-9.fc23.x86_64.rpm.
During installation,with this command

```
yum --nogpgcheck localinstall tomboy-1.15.4-9.fc23.x86_64.rpm
```

or

```
rpm -i tomboy-1.15.4-9.fc23.x86_64.rpm
```

I faced with dependencies error.
How can i install Tomboy in Cent-OS 7?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install Fedora 23 package on Centos 7. While it occasionally works, generally speaking it is very bad idea and rpm stopped you right before you done something wrong.

Either get EL7 version of that package. E.g from here: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/tpokorra/mono/

Or install Fedora 23 - e.g. in VM and install it there.